# Revert a svn folder to a previous revision

Tags: svn, version-control

To revert a particular folder in SVN to its previous state I currently use the following:

```
svn rm folder
svn commit -m 'removed folder to revert to previous version'
svn co http://pathto/repo/folder@268
cd folder
rm -rf .svn //recursively if many folders
svn add folder
svn commit -am 'reverted to the previous version'
```

Seems too much trouble for what should be a fairly common use case. I must be doing it wrong. How else can you do it?

Comment: unfortunately this procedure will not work since svn 1.7, because at this and next versions there is only one global .svn directory .

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Why not using `svn merge`?

Assuming you want to revert from current HEAD (last committed) version to revision 268:

```
cd folder
svn up
svn merge -r HEAD:268 .
```

Then resolve any conflicts manually (there should be nothing if there is no local change) and:

```
svn commit -m "- reverted to revision 268"
```

To revert single change (e.g. made in revision 666):

```
cd folder
svn merge -c -666 .
```

To revert local changes (not committed yet):

```
cd folder
svn revert -R .
```

Comment: I think there's a missing `-m` from the `svn commit` line above.  i.e. it should be `svn commit -m "- reverted to revision 268"`.  I can't edit because it's less than the 6 chars I'm limited to!

Answer (score 3):

Why not using 'svn merge'?
That's why: "Then resolve any conflicts manually[..]"

If I know 'folder' at revision 268 contains the consistent data I'd like to go on with, why automatically create a merge with potentially inconsistent data only to manually remove those changes later. It's error prone and defeats the purpose of my configuration management tool.

I.e. I'd prefer the recipe from the original request with a minor improvement. If you use 'svn export' to get the old revision you don't have to remove .svn files:

```
svn rm folder
svn commit -m 'removed folder to revert to previous version' .
svn export -r 268 http://pathto/repo/folder
svn add folder
svn commit -m 'reverted to the previous version' folder
```

Comment: You are going to revert a a folder... any uncommitted changes in this folder are not needed anymore, so before you use merge, you can use revert. Then there cannot be any conflicts...

Comment: Thanks. The accepted solution did not work for me (I had a special case where I needed to revert a "folder that was accidentally reverted to an earlier version" to a "newer" version again), but yours did. I had to change `svn export -r 268 http://pathto/repo/folder` to `svn export http://pathto/repo/folder@268`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svn merge` for this task, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s04.html#svn-ch-4-sect-4.2 for an example

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
svn revert folder/*
```

which will revert all the file under `folder`

Comment: from 'svn help revert':   ... This subcommand does not revert already committed changes...